# Customizeable solution base for "configurator" based on a defineable items catalog?

Tags: windows, open-source, configuration-management, product-management

I am looking for an open-source framework, or product, or customizeable app, that allows me to

- define items
- manage (create/edit/copy/delete/import/export/version-control) those items
- define and assign categories for those items
- manage (see above) compatibility rules for those items (for example by grouping them into categories, and specifying which item categories can be combined with which, forming an individual configuration)
- use a "configurator"-like functionality that allows me do plan the integration of items to form an custom (and buildable!) configuration.

It´s like a small car configurator: Based on a database that holds items, categories, and "compatibility" rules, it allows me to integrate the car of my choice in an interactive way, never offering me options that don´t match (like a       roof-mounted luggage rack for a cabriolet, nobody should be able to order that one!), so only buildable configurations can be created.

**So basically, I am looking for a customizeable solution that provides a domain-neutral base for building up and maintaining the database, and using it to create configurations.**

In this century of small-volume built-to-customer production, I cannot believe that one has to start from scratch for such a thing?

I bet that if there is a solution base, it will be open-source because one will want to tweak and integrate this in ways that no closed standard software package could provide.

*** Update ***
Oh, I forgot. Commercial software would be welcome, too, but I simply don´t think that will be flexible enough to be domain-agnostic. 
The platform should be Windows. 
It´s ok to install stuff on end user´s machines (no need to run in the browser). Also, so far no limits regarding other systems requirements, like database, RAM, or whatever.